# Quais os critérios que uso na hora de escolher quais APIs baixar?

Tags: android, api, sdk

Ou tem que baixar todas as que aparecerem no sdk? Sou beginner.

Comment: O primeiro critério é a compatibilidade(versão) da API com a sua plataforma hardware, os outros dependem dos requisitos do projeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso depende de qual público alvo de seu app e o nível de compatibilidade que você quer.

Você pode baixar a verão mais recente, mas se você quer que seu app seja compatível com versões antigas do Android, você deve definir a versão mínima.

Abaixo, está configurado para usar o SDK 21 (Lollipop), mas mantendo o suporte ao SDK 14 (Android 4.0)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.foo.meuapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

Ou AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

---

Atualmente, para suportar 90% dos Androids você deve desenvolver seu app com suporte mínimo à API 14 ([referência](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que baixar as que precisa, eu recomendo baixar a **2.3.3**

E todas da **4.4** pra cima.

Não baixe os "EXAMPLES", ao menos eu não considero necessário.

Em suma, baixe as que achar necessário.